# This function has a reified type parameter and thus can only be inlined at compilation time, not called directly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have the below code that compiles, but runtime crash

```
@Composable
fun Launcher() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        item {
            context.StartActivityButton<LaunchedEffectActivity>()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private inline fun <reified T : Activity>Context.StartActivityButton() {
    Button(onClick = {
        startActivity(Intent(this, T::class.java))
    }) {
        Text(T::class.toString())
    }
}
```

The error is

```
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This function has a reified type parameter and thus can only be inlined at compilation time, not called directly.
        at kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.throwUndefinedForReified(Intrinsics.java:207)
        at kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.throwUndefinedForReified(Intrinsics.java:201)
        at kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.needClassReification(Intrinsics.java:219)
        at com.example.composesideeffects.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt.<clinit>(MainActivity.kt:52)
        at com.example.composesideeffects.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I have already used `inline` for my `reified`. What did I miss?

Comment: StartActivityButton() cannot be inline as per exception have you tried removing inline ??

Comment: Without inline, the reified will not compile

Comment: Just speculating. Perhaps Compose does not inline the code of inline functions at compile time and therefore calls them like a normal function at runtime. But inline functions with reified types cannot be called like normal functions. That's why they're hidden from Java code. So, if this is the case, it's a shortcoming on the part of Compose not to show a compile-time error when it encounters functions with reified types.

Comment: I have file a bug report at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215402573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug, I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).

---

Inlining the action works fine:

```
private inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.startActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, T::class.java))
}
// ..
Button(onClick = {
    context.startActivity<MainActivity>()
}) {

}
```

---

Creating composable function as an extension on `Context` seems very strange to me: you can get `LocalContext.current` in any composable.

Here's how you can do the same without inlining:

```
@Composable
private fun StartActivityButton(activityClass: Class<*>) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Button(onClick = {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, activityClass))
    }) {
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
StartActivityButton(LaunchedEffectActivity::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks. Ya, I use the old conventional clazz Java style for now. Thanks!

Comment: I have file a bug report at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215402573

Comment: Curiously `koin-androidx-compose` library has functions like `@Composable fun <reified : T : Any> inject(args) : Lazy<T> { ... }` absolutely fine - https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin-compose/blob/main/koin-androidx-compose/src/main/java/org/koin/androidx/compose/ComposeExt.kt.  However whenever I tried creating my own within a kmm module, withing android sourceSet that includes compose extension functions, it completely failed to compile .. This issue seems related, but the issue tracker has had no movement in 6 months ... any further insights since January?

Comment: @Mark I believe it's not supported so far, in such cases I think it's appropriate to message on the issue, not sure wether they receive a notification just on someone hitting +1

Comment: Sure, I'll add +1. The problem isn't "directly" related as I'm using reified compose functions that won't then even compile (`compose Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't inline method call: CALL`) - gradle android block within a kmm module looks setup correctly including compose blocks like you would normally include. I know it's possible to use the reified compose functions- I'm using the library mentioned above that has them.  The only curve ball I guess is that its a kmm module .. I was just getting more insights - devs closest to the problem are most invested in fixing them.